# Fixing the height of the content-sidebar when contents exceed the min-height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've been trying for hours to fix this mistake but nothing seems to work

Here's the code, could someone please help me with it:

CSS:

```
#allContents{
    position:relative;

    width:980px;
    height:100%;
    min-height:850px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#allContents tr{
    height:100%;
}

#sidebar{
    float:left;

    width:225px;
    min-height:850px;
    padding:10px;
    padding-top:0px;

    text-align:center;

    background-color:#D8D8D8;
}

#sidebar .searchfield {
    width: 162px;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 8px;

    text-align:right;

    border: 1px solid #bcbbbb;
    border-radius: 2em;
    outline: medium none;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
}

#sidebar .searchbutton {width: 27px;
    height: 27px;

    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #494949;
    border-radius: 2em;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #9e9e9e, #454545) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);

    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#sidebar .searchform {
    display: inline-block;

    margin-top:20px;padding: 3px 5px;

    border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
    border-radius: 2em;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #fff, #ededed) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#sidebar .h-Line {
    margin:20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

#sidebar .Social li{
    display: block;
    float: left;

    width: 30%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top:30px;
    padding: 10px;

    text-align:center;
}

#sidebar .mainTitle{
    text-align:center;

    color:#555;

    font-size:16px;
}

#content{
    width:755px;
    min-height:850px;
    padding:20px;
    padding-top:0px;

    background-color:#EAE9E9;
}

#content #inside{
    float:right;

    padding:20px;

    text-align:right;
}

#content #inside h1{
    color:red;

    font-size:20px;
}

#content #inside h3{
    color:grey;

    font-size:16px;
}
#content #inside h2{
    color:black;

    font-size:18px;
}
```

and html

```
<html style="margin:0 auto;padding:0">
    <head>
         <title>khaldoun</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
         <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="innerBody" >
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="float:left;">
                        <?php include ('sidebar.php');?><!--Let's say that this one has 3 lines of text-->
                    </td>
                    <td style="float:right">
                        <?php include ('videoPageContainer.php');?> <!--Let's say that this one has 100 lines of text-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

sidebar.php

```
<div id="sidebar" style="float:left">
    <br>
    <form class="searchform">
        <input class="searchfield" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'search for'" placeholder="search for">
        <button class="searchbutton" type="button"><i class='fa fa-search'></i></button>
    </form>
    <ul class="Social">
        <a href="http://youtube.com" target="_blank"><li><img src="wp-content/themes/khaldountheme/images/youtube.png"></li></a>
        <a href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank"><li><img src="wp-content/themes/khaldountheme/images/twitter.png"></li></a>
        <a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank"><li><img src="wp-content/themes/khaldountheme/images/facebook.png"></li></a>
    </ul>
    <img src="wp-content/themes/khaldountheme/images/h-line.png" class="h-Line">
    <div class="mainTitle">last posts</div>

</div>
```

and videoPageContainer.php

```
<div id="content">
    <div id=inside>
                     <br>s<br><br><br>
                     <br>s<br><br><br>
                     <br>s<br><br><br>
                     <br>s<br><br><br>
                     <br>s<br><br><br>
                     <br>s<br><br><br>
                     <br>ddddddd<br><br><br>
                     <br>ddddddddd<br><br><br>
                     <br>ddddddd<br><br><br>
                     <br>ddd<br><br><br>
                     <br>ddd<br><br><br>
                     <br>ddd<br><br><br>
                     <br>s<br><br><br>
                     <br>s<br><br><br>
                     <br>s<br><br><br>
                     <br>s<br><br><br>
                     <br>s<br><br><br>
                     <br>s<br><br><br>
                     <br>s<br><br><br>
                     <br>s<br><br><br>
                     <br>s<br><br><br>
                     <br>s<br><br><br>
                     <br>s<br><br><br>
                     <br>s<br><br><br>
</div>
</div>
```

Every time the content exceeds the min-height, the added content is floating on the air, not even bgcolor is behind it, and the height of the two divs (container, and sidebar) remains fixed; any idea of how to make them flexible and both expand together?

Comment: First of all why are you using tables, they cause some or other problem all the time, just use div or span, they are easier to handle. But if want to use tables only then it will be better if you provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: Your CSS doesn't match your HTML.... `#innerBody` is nowhere to be found in your CSS, and all the elements you have in your CSS arent to be found in the HTML... are you sure this is the right combination of code?

Comment: I'll show you the sidebar and the container.. I'll edit it now wait a second

Answer (score 0):

You can use this javascript code for set min-height of `td` according to height of its parent `tr`

This code set table row `td:first-child` min-height to height of parent table row `tr`.

```
jQuery('table tr td:first-child').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).css({
        height: jQuery(this).closest('tr').css('height')
    })
});
```